# Node .JS Client Side Sensor Data on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspbian

all.

I have a raspberry pi running a node.JS web app that uses Express to serve up a static html page. The web app simply runs on localhost, on an instance of chrome. The webpage does not need to be accessed by anything but the pi, so I'm essentially using the node environment and html as my UI for the project.

I'm just wondering how I can get data from the GPIO (using onoff npm library) onto the webpage.

Interactions with the GPIO would be considered server side, whilst the HTML webpage and any javascript running on it is client side.

How can I read from a GPIO and update the locally served webpage in realtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some form of web service.

At the simplest level, this will be an HTTP server which generates an HTML document with the data in it on demand.

If you want to get more complicated, poll the server with Ajax and have it return the data to client-side JS.

A step further would involve the use of WebSockets (consider Sockets.io) to push the data to the client.